# search by elasticsearch-model not returns the records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch-model

I'm using elasticsearch-model and I used concern approach and here is my search method.I have tried my query by curl it returns me back 5 entries but when I used this method

```
def search_index(*args)
      self.__elasticsearch__.search(*args)
end
```

it's returns me a class

```
(byebug) Entry.search_index('test').records
#<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Records:0x007f8eb85ca280 @klass=[PROXY] Entry(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, source_id: integer, data: text, uuid: string, source_entry_id: string, bytesize: integer), @response=#<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Response:0x007f8eb85ca370 @klass=[PROXY] Entry(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, source_id: integer, data: text, uuid: string, source_entry_id: string, bytesize: integer), @search=#<Elasticsearch::Model::Searching::SearchRequest:0x007f8eb85ca438 @klass=[PROXY] Entry(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, source_id: integer, data: text, uuid: string, source_entry_id: string, bytesize: integer), @options={}, @definition={:index=>"self_driving_entries", :type=>"entry", :q=>"test"}>, @records=#<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Records:0x007f8eb85ca280 ...>>, @options={}>
```

how can I have access to my records by this search method ?

Comment: Have you tried calling `to_a` on the result?

Comment: What happens when you do a `Entry.search_index('test').records.to_a`? This class contains "PROXY" in it, which suggests that this class is just a *proxy* for the records list.

Comment: @MrYoshiji but still I don't undrestand why I need to convert it to array , records is an object from Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Records < Object so it should be printable right ?

Comment: It is printable, but the way you are printing it is asking the **proxy** to be printed, not the actual records. When you do a simple `User.where(true)` in the console, the output looks like an Array, but if you do `User.where(true).class`, you will see it is not an Array but an from the **proxy** class ActiveRecord::Relation.

Comment: in your byebug, I am pretty sure you can do `Entry.search_index('test').records.first` to return the first entry matching the conditions (if there is any)

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

You should use to your

> respond

```
records
```

Like Example

```
Foo.new().search('1234').response.records
```

It will return your Active record objects.